# Kendo MVC Grid Frozen Column Inline Edit click duplicate row coming in edit mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

I have a kendo grid with frozen column & inline editing is enabled, first  4 column is frozen and rest all columns are editable. the issue is when I add a new row with oust save/cancel if I click on edit (edit button) of any other row then the same rows appear editable duplicate and no save or cancel button. Please find the screenshot and help me to resolve this.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHUJU.png)